# Jquery Wait Until AJAX Call is Done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax function for saving a forms data. I want it to remain asynchronous because the users can hit save any time. However, I have another function that converts the form to a PDF and I want it to run the save function before creating the PDF (in case the users have added more data). Is there a way to make `$('input.submit')` wait for save to finish before opening the pdf? Below is the jQuery I am using:

```
$("button#save").on('click', function (){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo matry::base_to('utilities/crm/field_day_save');?>',
                    data: $("form#trip_form").serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        $("#alerts").html(data.alert);
                        $("#form_id").val(data.id);
                    }
                    });
            });
        $("input.submit").on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("button#save").trigger('click');
            window.open('<?php echo matry::base_to('custom_worddocs/field_day');?>' + '&fd_id=' + $("#form_id").val());
        });
```

In short, I want `$('button#save').click()` to remain asynchronous, but I want `$(input.submit)` to wait for button save to complete before opening new window.

Comment: You open the pdf in the `success` or `complete` callbacks of the ajax request.

Comment: Why are you triggering the click again?

Comment: The click is to run the ajax save function, so it saves before creating the pdf. @Danny, I don't want to have to rewrite the save function with just an additional line for opening the window, and I don't want the window to open every time its saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your click handler return a promise object, then use `triggerHandler()` to trigger the click event and get it's return value.

```
$("button#save").on('click', function (){
    return $.ajax({
        ...
```

and

```
...
$("button#save").triggerHandler('click').done(function(){
    window.open(...);
});
...
```

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/SRzcy/

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object which, among other things, behaves like a [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

By only calling `window.open` from within the [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) function, it'll wait for the AJAX to complete:

```
$("button#save").on('click', function () {

    var jqXHR = $.ajax({ /* your config... */ });

    $("input.submit").one('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("button#save").trigger('click');

        jqXHR.then(function () {
            window.open('<?php echo matry::base_to('custom_worddocs/field_day');?>' + '&fd_id=' + $("#form_id").val());
        });
    });

}
```